# implement function as object in PHP

Tags: php, function, object

Is it possible to implement functions as object instances in PHP? I'm used to doing this in Java with the code below, but I can't seem to find a similar approach in PHP. Is it possible?

```
interface OneVarFunction {
    public int eval(int x);
}
static void routine() {
    OneVarFunction func1 = new OneVarFunction() {
        public Boolean eval(int x) {
            return x*x;
        }
    };
    OneVarFunction func2 = new OneVarFunction() {
        public Boolean eval(int x) {
            return 2*x+1;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible in PHP7+

in your case, an example would be

```
interface OneVarFunction {
    public function eval($x);
}

//...

$test = new class implements OneVarFunction {
    public function eval($x) {
        return $x*$x;
    }
};
```

For more information, see the corresponding site of the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php), which also provides further examples.

It is not possible in versions prior to PHP7, though.